# AsyncTask and XmlPullParser

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am trying to make a WeatherApp, don't know where can I put 'AsyncTask' code here.

This is my first XmlPullParser code and if you know how to solve it, please let me know!

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    getData getdata;

    TextView tv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tv= (TextView ) findViewById(R.id.tv);
        getdata = (getData) new getData().execute(null, null, null);
    }

public class getData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    boolean flag = false;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled(Void aVoid) {
        super.onCancelled(aVoid);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try{
            URL url = new URL("http://www.kma.go.kr/weather/forecast/mid-term-rss3.jsp?stnId=109");

            XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
            XmlPullParser parser = factory.newPullParser();
            parser.setInput(url.openStream(), "utf-8");

            String tag = null;
            String city = null, mode = null, tmEf = null, wf = null, tmn = null, tmx = null, reliability = null;

            int eventType = parser.getEventType();

            while(eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {

                if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                    tag = parser.getName();

                } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {

                    if(tag.equals("mode")) {
                        mode = parser.getText();
                    } else if (tag.equals("tmEf")) {
                        tmEf = parser.getText();
                    } else if (tag.equals("wf")) {
                        wf = parser.getText();
                    } else if (tag.equals("tmn")) {
                        tmn = parser.getText();
                    } else if (tag.equals("tmx")) {
                        tmx = parser.getText();
                    } else if (tag.equals("reliability")) {
                        reliability = parser.getText();
                    } else if (tag.equals("city")) {
                        city = parser.getText();
                    }
                } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
                    tag = parser.getName();
                    if(tag.equals("location")) {
                        break;
                    }
                } eventType = parser.next();
            } flag = true;
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    }
```

Comment: What is the actual problem you have? You posted code but didn't ask any question.

Comment: What is the problem exactly? Are you getting an error somewhere?

Comment: you can look at this: https://androidtutorialmagic.wordpress.com/android-asynctask-and-its-dark-side/asynctask-tutorial/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Don't give a name from small character - getData is not a good name for a class in java - it looks like a method not like a class - type. 
Good name should looks like: GetDataAsync.

2) Better place for call async task will be onResume() method.

3) 
`getdata = (getData) new getData().execute(null, null, null);`
here can be a problem - you try cast void type to getData type

4)  update your UI in onPostExecute

5) maybe doInBackground method should return some value which can be used in onPostExecute method